# Tuxcut -software in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I need to know how [Tuxcut](https://bitbucket.org/a_atalla/tuxcut/wiki/Home) works. I am using it to cut the IP address of other computers in my subnet (Local Area Network) in college.

I have searched but haven't found anything.

I'm using TuxCut in X-Ubuntu and is not displaying any computers in my networks.. It only shows router's ip address....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IP which you pass as argument to tuxcut, is sent a packet telling him that its gateway's MAC address is your MAC address. Hence, that IP sends all the packets to you and if you don't forward it to the actual gateway, they're silently dropped.

E.g. If there are two PCs in a subnet, whose IP addresses are `IP_A` and `IP_B` and their MAC addresses are `MAC_A` and `MAC_B`.

Suppose that the PC with IP `IP_A` tries to cut the net of PC with IP `IP_B`.

As you know, every PC before sending a packet asks for the MAC address of the gateway if it is not available on its cache. So when the PC with IP `IP_B` sends ARP Request for the MAC address of its gateway, it does that by MAC level broadcast: destination MAC is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.

`IP_A` PC replies to this with the ARP reply, which is unicast as sends its MAC (`MAC_A`) as the MAC address of gateway. So `IP_B` sends all packets to `IP_A` which doesn't forward the packet to actual gateway.

**P.S.:** You can check this by using Wireshark while using Tuxcut.

Comment: is this related with ARP poisining?

Comment: @Arya: It is an ARP Poisoning Attack.